# Question on branches and $\iff$.

Tags: complex-analysis, logic

For real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ of a real variable $x$, is the statement

$$f(x)+ig(x)=0\iff e^{f(x)}(\cos(g(x))+i\sin(g(x)))=1,$$

correct?

I'm concerned about the branch when taking the logarithm for the  $\Longleftarrow$ implication.

After a little thought I was thinking that if I were to specify a branch first then this would be ok? Something like,

"Let $h(x)=f(x)+ig(x)$ be defined on the principal branch only. Then it follows that
$$h(x)=0\iff e^{f(x)}(\cos(g(x))+i\sin(g(x)))=1."$$

EDIT

I'm only interested in continuous functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Neither side is a statement, so the use of $\Longleftrightarrow$ is not appropriate.  If both sides were equations then it would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the forward direction is true. Suppose that $e^{f(x)+ig(x)} = 1$, then by equating real and imaginary parts, we see that $e^{f(x)}\sin(g(x)) = 0$. Since $e^y\neq 0$ for any $y$, it must be the case that $\sin(g(x)) = 0$ for all $x$, i.e. $g(x) = n_x\pi$ for some $n_x\in\Bbb N$.

Note here that I do not assume any smoothness properties about $g$. It could be discontinuous. If we make the assumption that it is continuous (or even measurable), then $g$ is (effectively) uniquely determined.

Working with the real part now, we have that $e^{f(x)}\cos(g(x)) = 1$. Since $g(x) = n_x\pi$, we get $e^{f(x)}\cos(n_x\pi) = 1$. Since $e^{f(x)}>0$ for all $x$, it must be the case that $\cos(n_x\pi)$ is positive, i.e. $n_x$ is even for every $x$ which in turn implies that $f\equiv 0$.

Thus we can't quite infer that $f+ig \equiv 0$; only that $f\equiv 0$ and $g(x) = 2m_x\pi$ for some $m_x\in\Bbb N$. $g$ doesn't even need to be continuous. *However* if you do restrict your attention to the principal branch, it is true as you suggest. In fact, if you make any branch choice, then $g$ is uniquely determined and is a constant.

Comment: Thank you. So if I restrict my attention to the principal branch (and I will also assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous) then $f+ig=0\iff e^{f(x)}\cos(g(x))+ie^{f(x)}\sin(g(x))=1$ ?

Comment: You don't need to assume continuity once you fix a branch. We already knew that $f\equiv 0$ without assuming any sort of continuity - we got it for free. As soon as you fix a branch, $g(x)$ can only be a *specific* multiple of $2\pi$ (since it is functioning as the argument for $\cos$ and $\sin$); again, you get continuity and constancy for free.